# Geometric Vectors

Tags: vectors

In a triangle ABC the altitude to AB is CD.
mark: $\vec{CA}=\underline{u}, \ \vec{CB}=\underline{v}, \ \vec{AD}=t \vec{AB}$.

we know that $|\vec{CA}|=1, \ |\vec{CB}|=2, \ \cos \angle ACB = \frac{3}{4}  $

1. Find t
2. Draw the triangle ABC and CD such that it will match the value of t that you found.
3. A point E is on BC between B and C such that $\frac{CE}{BE} = \frac{3}{5}$, let's mark $\vec{CD}=\underline{h}$. Express $\vec{AE}$ with only $\underline{u}$ and $\underline{h}$.

I solved the 1 and 2:

1. $t=-\frac{1}{4}$
2. [image]

But I can't express $\vec{AE}$ with only $\underline{u}$ and $\underline{h}$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator you write, its CD=h I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that you have solved parts (a) and (b) correctly and am not calculating it myself.

Note that $\dfrac {CE}{BE}=\dfrac 35$, so that $$\vec {CE}=\frac {3}{3+5}\vec {CB}=\frac 38\vec {CB}=\frac38\vec v.$$
Now, notice that in $\triangle ACE$, $\vec {CE}=\vec{CA}+\vec {AE}$ so that $$\vec {AE}=\frac 38\vec v-\vec u.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
Now, notice again, in $\triangle CAD$, $$\vec h=\vec {CA}+\vec{AD}=\vec u+\left(-\dfrac14\right)(\vec v-\vec u)$$$$=\frac{5\vec u-\vec v}{4}$$ so that $$\vec v=5\vec u-4\vec h.$$ Substituting the value of $\vec v$ in $(1)$, we get $$\vec {AE}=\frac78\vec u-\frac 32\vec h.$$